# Defining date attributes in openldap

Tags: openldap, date, attributes

There doesn't appear to be a standard date syntax.  How do people handle entering dates into ldap so that they are comparable and invalid data can't be entered?  I'm hoping to enforce a fairly standard format such as `YYYY-mm-dd`.  Other people have to have done this before but I can't seem to find anything.  Anyone have suggestions or links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There doesn't appear to be a standard date syntax.

The standard representation of time/date information uses the "generalized time" syntax, defined in [RFC 4517](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#section-3.3.13).  This is used by OpenLDAP, Active Directory, other directory servers, and elsewhere.

Comment: So people normally just zero out the time fields?  No way to do dates only?

Comment: That would seem to be the logical way of handling it.  There is of course no requirement that you use this particular standard.  If you're writing your own application, you can pick your own format and do you own data validation, so it doesn't matter all that much.

Comment: I may want to be able to use some of them in search filters so I guess I'll go with the standard unless there's a way I can define my own matching rules.